# Xcode Unit Testing with C++: candidate found by name lookup is and reference is ambiguous

Tags: c++, xcode, objective-c++

I am trying to move a few tests into the XCTest target of my application in Xcode. The library I am testing functionalities for is large, and I include its header files inside my tests.mm file (my Obj-C++ testing file where all unit test cases are).

For one specific "Size" type, Compiler reports a series of ambiguous clashes with the Size type already defined as part of the SDK for MacOS10.13 (in /usr/include). Here is how the #include set for my testing file looks like:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>.   <---- defines Size, which clashes with MacTypes.h definition
#include <Analytics/all.hpp>
#include <boost/timer.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <random>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>

using namespace src::Utilities;
using namespace src::Simulation;
using namespace src::MarketData;
using namespace src::detail;
using namespace std::placeholders;

//...More code down here, but not problematic
```

is the file which contains the definition for Size. Can someone please help spot where I may have gone wrong, especially that when I run the tests as part of a giant Main() function, it all works fine.

Thanks,
Amine

Comment: I think the question above boils down to  name collision happen between User defined library and the MacOS SDK. Any links/advice on how to properly solve it without the need to refactor the user supplied code will be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update: After some research, I think I found what was going on with this issue: "using namespace xxxx" inside Objective-C++ testing framework instead of fully qualifying the data types with xxxx:: clashes with native Apple API types (Size, Handle, ptr, etc...). Full namespace qualification of C++ data types is required in this case to avoid ambiguity.